# Как узнать каким пользователем занят файл в сети?

Tags: c#

Есть сетевой *.xls*-файл.

Как можно программно узнать, каким пользователем занят данный файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По всей видимости узнать это можно только с машины, на которой находится папка, содержащая файл. На ней должен быть поднят сервис, проверяющий по запросу кто именно занял файл. Другие же клиенты сети для проверки должны посылать запросы на этот сервис.

Вот [проект на CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10760/An-app-to-see-who-has-files-open-on-a-network-serv), автор которого решил эту проблему.

Comment: Автор, мягко говоря, впер костыль.

Comment: Сложно спорить. Но это решение и оно работает

Comment: Можно развить идею и сделать костыль менее "костяным": Оставить концепцию сервиса на машине, где расположена "шара", но сервис не должен быть сетевым, он должен лишь создавать рядом с занятым файлом на "шаре" файл с таким же именем и расширением ".block", в котором будет описано кем в данный момент занят файл. При освобождении файла, файл ".block" должен удаляться сервисом. То есть наличие файла 1.xls.block будет означать, что файл 1.xls занят, а содержимое этого файла укажет кем именно он занят.

Answer (score 3):

[Попробуйте запосить DirectoryServices](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/270123-how-enumerate-open-files-using-directoryservices)

```
using (DirectoryEntry container = new
DirectoryEntry("WinNT://servername/LanmanServer")
{
    IADsFileServiceOperations fso= container.NativeObject as
    IADsFileServiceOperations;
    if (fso != null)
    {
        foreach(IADsSession sess in fso.Sessions()) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name : {0} \tUser: {1} \tComputer : {2}",
            sess.Name, sess.User, sess.Computer);
        }

        IADsCollection resources = fso.Resources() as IADsCollection;
        Console.WriteLine("----- Resource info -------");
        foreach(IADsResource resource in resources)
        {
            try
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("\tPath: {0}\tUser: {1}\tLockCount: {2}\tName:
            {3}",
            resource.Path, resource.User, resource.LockCount,
            resource.Name);
            }
            catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException ex)
            {
                // Watch Non-Fileshare resources like named pipes, these are not
               stored in the ADSI cache
            }
        }
    }
}
```